# CakePHP with application mobile

Tags: angular, cakephp, ionic-framework

I have already developed a website with cakephp and I would like to develop a mobile application (native with ionic and angular) that will call the majority of functions in the site.

To use this application, the user must log on.
According to the library, cakephp uses cookies to identify a user already connected.

I would like to know how with cakephp I will be able to identify the mobile client?

thank you very much.

Comment: Make a REST api for the mobile app. This is a good resource to start http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/

Comment: Thank you . ADmad